# ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator triggered from separate div

Tags: html, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a table for user input, to add new employees. And for the attribute ID I want it to be required so I am using RequiredFieldValidator like this:

```
<td>ID:</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="AddIdTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="AddIdRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="AddIdTextBox"
        ErrorMessage="ID is required"
        ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

On the same page but in another div, I have a ListView that shows all employees. When I click a button that is suppose to delete an employee, and If I did not enter an ID on the textbox above, the RequiredFieldValidator does not alow it.

Is it possible solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ValidationGroup` in the Validator and the corresponding Button that submits those fields.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="AddIdRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="AddIdTextBox"
    ErrorMessage="ID is required"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ValidationGroup="Group1">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

And also the Button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero! That was a top notch answer.